# Unable to download Bluemix starter code

Tags: download, ibm-cloud

I have created multiple applications from boilerplate templates and for some reason, it is no longer possible to download the Starter Code. I open the application panel, select Start Coding in the left pane, then select Eclipse Tools for Bluemix. Further down, as expected, there is a "Download Starter Code" button, but it links back to bluemix.net instead of to a code archive file. Has anyone seen this? I have deleted / re-created the apps many times, but it never produces an archive. I have seen several posts here on Starter Code, but none specifically with this issue.

Comment: Which boilerplate are you looking for?

Comment: This is a defect. I recommend opening a support ticket. Try clicking on 'Add Git' to see the code on a devops services project. You can also find some boilerplates here https://github.com/IBM-Bluemix

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In some cases this behaviour is related to the browser language setting. Try setting it to English (if you use another language) and check if the download button url now points to the correct zip.

Another possible workaround is to instantiate one of the boilerplates and then click on the Add Git button at the top right hand of the screen when viewing the overview of the running app. Using the Add Git button on a boilerplate (or runtime) instantiated app you can see the sample code in DevOps Service. You can download it from there or you could git clone the repository and get the code that way.

Alternatively please take a look at the [IBM Bluemix repo on GitHub](https://github.com/IBM-Bluemix).

Comment: This is the best way to go about it!

Answer (score -1):

you can do same by three ways you can also clone git repository of starter code or you can download commandline interface and fallow instruction

for me while developing node application download eclipse archive worked fine